# How to split screenshot of text at individual words?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a screenshot of a single line of text, like this:

[image: screenshot]

The text is black on a white background.  Does ImageMagick have a command to identify the positions of the white spaces between words?

It would need a threshold so it doesn't get confused by the much smaller white spaces between individual letters.

The purpose is to split the image into pictures of individual words.  The example image would be split into 3 images: stack, over, & flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in ImageMagick by using morphology to blend the letters in each word together so that you have one black region for each. Then use connected components to get their bounding boxes. Then crop the image from the bounding boxes.

In ImageMagick 6 in Unix syntax:

Input:

[image]

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
bboxArr=(`convert stackoverflow.png +repage \
-morphology erode rectangle:9x100 +repage \
-threshold 0 -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 null: | grep "gray(0)" | awk '{print $2}'`)
IFS=$OLDIFS
num=${#bboxArr[*]}
echo $num
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox=${bboxArr[$i]}
echo "$i $bbox"
convert stackoverflow.png +repage -crop $bbox +repage stackoverflow_word_$i.png
done
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]